# frox as reverse proxy?

Tags: ftp, reverse-proxy

I have 'frox' setup as the ftp proxy on one of my servers, but I need to have all traffic to this system to be forwarded to another ftp server.  I know about transparent forwarding, but I can't seem to get it to work nor find great documentation.  One of my requirements is that only a username WITHOUT the destination server be entered, e.g. ftpuser instead of ftpuser@ftpserver.server.com

Here is a copy of my current conf file:

```
Port 2121
BindToDevice eth0
ResolvLoadHack wontresolve.doesntexist.abc
User frox
Group frox
WorkingDir /var/cache/frox
 DontChroot Yes
LogLevel 20
LogFile /var/log/frox.log
PidFile  /var/cache/frox/frox.pid
BounceDefend yes
 CacheModule local
 CacheSize 400
 CacheAll no   # Set to yes to cache non anonymous ftp downloads
MaxForks 60
MaxForksPerHost 4
ACL Allow * - *
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the rp patch from http://www.nagilum.org/frox/ .
Then you'll get two new configuration options:

```
# Hardwire the NTP to a destination server
# this allows frox to act as a reverse proxy
#
#NTPProxyDest ftp.example.com:21

# Change the default greeting when running in NTP mode
#
#NTPGreeting "Welcome to ftp.example.com"
```

That should do what you want..